# InfoPath non-editable fields

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I've created a simple list in SharePoint 2010. It has a couple of text columns and a couple of  integer columns.

1. I click "Customize Form" from the Sharepoint Ribbon
2. InfoPath 2010 is launched
3. I make the form look nice and ensure fields are bound to correct columns
4. I upload the form back to Sharepoint

When I click to "Add new item" my InfoPath form is displayed. However only one of the field is editable. I can click into the other fields but when I hit the keyboard - nothing!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Rob.

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields in question might have been set to Read-only. Double-check using the following steps:

1. Use "Customize Form" again from the Sharepoint Ribbon
2. Right click each Control in question
3. Click Properties
4. Click the Display Tab
5. Ensure that the `Read-only` checkbox is unticked.